# Error : TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable while using lops in python

Tags: python, list, loops, nlp

I am using python, i have a nested list like this

```
clusters_appearance_list = [[[0, 0], ['jack']], [[0, 0], ['study']], [[0, 4], ['small', 'modest', 'little']], [[0, 5], ['big', 'large']]]
```

I want to calculate the frequency of each cluster in a text. My code is like this

```
for cluster in clusters_appearance_list:
  for word_cluster in cluster:
    for word in words_cluster[1]:
        for sentence in stemmed_sentences_list:
            if word in sentence[1]:
                count = count+1
     clusters_appearance_list.append(count)
     count = 0
print(clusters_appearance_list)
```

I get error in

```
for word in cluster[1]:
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: I don't get the logic behind the `cluster[1]`. What do you think it is doing. And why do you even need it? Also, your indentation is messed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
for cluster in clusters_appearance_list:
    for word in cluster[1]:
```

not the

```
for cluster in clusters_appearance_list:
   for word_cluster in cluster:
     for word in words_cluster[1]:
```